# Difference between beforeRouteUpdate and watching '$route' - Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

As we know, to react to params changes in the same component we use `beforeRouteUpdate` hook or watching `$route`.

**watching $route:**

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```

**beforeRouteUpdate Method:**

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // react to route changes...
    next()
  }
}
```

What is the difference between these two? if both are same then why vue router introduced `beforeRouteUpdate`?

Answer (score 20):

From the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#using-the-options-api) on `beforeRouteUpdate`:

> called when the route that renders this component has changed, but this component is reused in the new route. For example, given a route with params `/users/:id`, when we navigate between `/users/1` and `/users/2`, the same `UserDetails` component instance will be reused, and this hook will be called when that happens. Because the component is mounted while this happens, the navigation guard has access to `this` component instance.

The documentation is admittedly unclear that the hook gets called *before* the value of the `$route` object actually changes. That's the difference between this navigation hook and setting a watcher on `$route`, which will get called *after* the value of `$route` has changed.

Using the `beforeRouteUpdate` navigation guard, you can determine whether or not you want to prevent the route from changing (by not calling `next()`) or go to a different route entirely (by passing a different route value like `next('/foo')`, `next({ name: 'foo' })`, etc.).

Here's an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hjpf5oL/1) that shows when these functions get called.

Comment: only change the id  can reuse the `/foo/:id` component; but `/foo/1` & `/foo` is not the same component! 

https://github.com/xgqfrms/vue/issues/57

Comment: Additionally, `$route` watcher runs even when the route of the respective component's does not change (but the one of a child component). `beforeRouteUpdate` is specific to the current component only.

Comment: can anyone update the documentation link?

Answer (score 2):

As @thanksd said `$route` is like guard. With watching you can't prevent the route from taking action, but with `beforeRouteUpdate` you can do it with `next` function. for example you can wait untill your data is fetched then proceed to the component.

You can find more information in vue-router documentation [Data Fetching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html).