# How to get current name of a router in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

In App includes `nav` component, what I want to do is if you access to website not through main page, but from children page for instance `some_url/boys` it selects in Navigation that block.So I'm thinking whats the best way to get name of a router? I thought probably straight in `Nav` component with the help of `beforeRouteUpdate` hook get the name of router, but it doesnt want enter it at all. Here is a logic of my component

```
import MenuBar from "@/store/menu.js";

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    name: "TheNav",
    data(){
        return {
            menu: MenuBar.navBar
        }
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) { // dosn't print anything!
        console.log(1);
        console.log(this.$route.name);
        next()
    },
    methods: {
        ft_click(e, i) // that's animation method, nevermind
        {
            this.menu.forEach( (el) => {
                el.styleNavBar.width = 0 + '%';
                el.active = false;
            })
            this.menu[i].active = true;
            this.menu[i].styleNavBar.width = 80 + '%';
        },
        ft_hover(e, i, width) // that's animation method, nevermind
        {
            if(this.menu[i].active !== true)
            this.menu[i].styleNavBar.width = width + '%';
        }
    }
}
```

So same question, How to get current name of a router in Vue? Or why my hook doesnt want to work (((

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47185560/7499069) you can get the idea that it's not clear `$route` is updated when the `beforeRouteUpdate` is called. `beforeRouteUpdate` is using for determining to approve or prevent the `next`. You can get the current name using computed or watch property.

Comment: I don't know believe it or not I spent whole day figuring out and still I got nothingg... I wrote     mounted()
    {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.name);
      })
    }  in App component and still it return me null ......